# Compute using different variable types

Tags: java, java-8

I'm reading *Java: The Complete Reference by Herbert Schildt* right now and here is one thing that is not really clear for me. In the chapter about Integers it says that the **long** type should be used when big, whole numbers are needed. The code example from the book:

```
// Compute distance light travels using long variables

class Light {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int lightspeed;
        long days;
        long seconds;
        long distance;

        // approximate speed of light in miles per second

        lightspeed = 18600;

        days = 1000; // specify number of days here

        seconds = days * 24 * 60 * 60; // convert to seconds

        distance = lightspeed * seconds; // compute distance

        System.out.print("In " + days + " days light will travel about " + distance + " miles.");

    }
}
```

Upon execution console provides me with such the result:

```
"In 1000 days light will travel about 16070400000000 miles."
```

According by my logic, days and seconds vars should be **int** too, while their values are less than 2 147 483 647.

At this example days = 1000 and seconds = 86 400 000, so the values aren't that big.

But when I declare variables like this:

```
int lightspeed, days, seconds;
long distance;
```

I've strange result and for now I can accept it at no way.

```
"In 1000 days light will travel about -1367621632 miles."
```

Help me please.

Comment: The speed of light, approximately 186,000 miles per second, is off by a factor of 10, here. (c. 186,282.4 mi/s.)

Comment: You should *really* think about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI when programming. Don’t use miles. Learn the [lessons from history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter)

Comment: @Holger it was just a fragment of code from the book, but yes I'm totally agree with you I should pay more attention to systems I use and avoid non-SI units. This history is useful and instructive. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When both `seconds` and `lightspeed` are declared as `int`, `lightspeed * seconds` is computed as the multiplication of `int`s, which causes an overflow (since 16070400000000 > 2147483647).

You can still leave them as `int` if you cast `lightspeed` or `seconds` to `long`, which will force the multiplication to be performed on `long`s :

```
distance = (long)lightspeed * seconds;
```

or

```
distance = lightspeed * (long)seconds;
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I've got an idea. You made it clear for me now. Thus, "days" can be safety used as "int" with no problems at all, right?

Comment: @Mike Assuming `days * 24 * 60 * 60` can never pass 2^31-1 then `days` and `seconds` can both be `int`. And in the second calculation, at least one of the operands must be long (or cast to long) to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, only the distance is relevant, as Eran pointed out.

This behaviour is quite easy to remember if you just think of divison.

as above `a / b` performs integer division (truncation) given that a and b are integers whereas

```
(double) a / b
```

would return a double.

Note that the cast always refers to what follows after it. so in the case of an expression comprising of two integers **only** the first integer is casted to double.

`